# How to do a Hovertip for just the Label of a Labelframe in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tooltip, ttk

i want to show a tooltip when hovering over the info-symbol of my labelframe.

[image]

I've already tried several approaches but nothing seems to be working.

```
#Approach1:
Infolabel = ttk.Label(text="\U0001F6C8")
mylabelframe = ttk.Labelframe(self, text=f"TEC Settings {Infolabel}")
Hovertip(Infolabel, "Hello World")
```

-> wont show the Infosign and the Hovertip, it shows "TEC Settings .!label"

```
#Approach2:
Infolabel = f"\U0001F6C8"
mylabelframe = ttk.Labelframe(self, text=f"TEC Settings {Infolabel}")
Hovertip(Infolabel, "Hello World")
```

-> shows the Infosign, but it wont show the Hovertip

I already tried to give the Hovertip function the whole labelframe, but then the hovertip gets shown all over the labelframe.

Does anybody know a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tkinter widget as the label of `LabelFrame` via the `labelwidget` option, so you can create a custom frame widget which contains two labels. The first label is the text and the second label is the info symbol.  Then you can bind the hover tooltip on the info symbol only:

```py
# create a frame with two labels
frame = Frame(root)
Label(frame, text="TEC Settings").pack(side=LEFT)
info = Label(frame, text="\U0001F6C8")
info.pack(side=LEFT)
Hovertip(info, "Hello World") # bind the tooltip to the info-symbol

mylabelframe = ttk.Labelframe(root, labelwidget=frame)
mylabelframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```